# creating list of objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to do create a `list` of your own objects in `Javascript`?  This is the type of data I want to store :

```
Date : 12/1/2011   Reading : 3   ID : 20055    
Date : 13/1/2011   Reading : 5   ID : 20053    
Date : 14/1/2011   Reading : 6   ID : 45652
```

Comment: List does not works on javascript. It will show "List not defined" error in console. You can try Array, Set, Map etc for this purpose.

Answer (score 186, accepted):

```
var list = [
    { date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    { date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    { date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];
```

and then access it:

```
alert(list[1].date);
```

Comment: I would be adding each item to the list individually, what would be the correct syntax to do that?

Comment: i think it would be like that 
list[list.length]= {date : '11/11/1999',reading:3,id=1};
Regards

Comment: @user517406, like this: `var list = []; list.push({ date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 });`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov would accessing individual records be easier or more efficient by creating an object with unique id's as properties? The date and reading being properties of each id node? In other words `var myReadings = {}` then access values with `myReadings.20055.reading`? Build it out by looping your array, for example `myReadings[list[0]["id"]] = list[0]["id"];` Or, is performance the same - array of objects vs object w properties?

Answer (score 74):

dynamically build list of objects

```
var listOfObjects = [];
var a = ["car", "bike", "scooter"];
a.forEach(function(entry) {
    var singleObj = {};
    singleObj['type'] = 'vehicle';
    singleObj['value'] = entry;
    listOfObjects.push(singleObj);
});
```

here's a working example http://jsfiddle.net/b9f6Q/2/
see console for output

Answer (score 29):

Maybe you can create an array like this:

```
var myList = new Array();
myList.push('Hello');
myList.push('bye');

for (var i = 0; i < myList .length; i ++ ){
    window.console.log(myList[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Going off of [tbradley22's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24747608/7487335), but using `.map` instead:

```
var a = ["car", "bike", "scooter"];
a.map(function(entry) {
    var singleObj = {};
    singleObj['type'] = 'vehicle';
    singleObj['value'] = entry;
    return singleObj;
});
```

Comment: Why use map? Asking because I really don't know, not to be "clever" ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the array

```
  list = new Array()
```

push non-undefined value to the list

```
    var text = list.forEach(function(currentValue, currentIndex, listObj) {
    if(currentValue.text !== undefined)
    {list.push(currentValue.text)}
    });
```

Answer (score -6):

So, I'm used to using

```
var nameOfList = new List("objectName", "objectName", "objectName")
```

This is how it works for me but might be different for you, I recommend to watch some Unity Tutorials on the Scripting API.

Comment: List does not works on javascript. It will show "List not defined" error in console.

Comment: Unity Scripting != Javascript.