# how to create list of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
        var employee =
        {
            Column1: null,
            Column2: null,

            create: function () {
                var obj = new Object();

                obj.Column1 = "";
                obj.Column2 = "";

                return obj;
            }
        };
```

In C# I would do something like this:

```
List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Employee emp = new Employee()
    {
        Column1 = "column 1 of emp" + i;
        Column2 = "column 2 of emp" + i;
    }
    employees.Add(emp);
}
```

I need to do the same in javascript.

Comment: Have you heard about arrays? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object, http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html. Should be covered in every JavaScript tutorial.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868850/creating-list-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pretty straight forward approach to creating an array of objects.

```
var employees = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    employees.push({
        Column1: 'column 1 of emp' + i,
        Column2: 'column 1 of emp' + i
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6):

It's a Old question but just wanna contribute to it. I used [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

```js
function car(brand, color, year, price) {
    this.brand = brand;
    this.color = color;
    this.year = year;
    this.price = price;
}

var my = new Array();
my.push(new car("Ford", "Black", 2017, 15000));
my.push(new car("Hyundai", "Red", 2017, 17000));

document.getElementById('ford').value = my[0].price;
document.getElementById('hyundai').value = my[1].price;
```

```html
Ford price: <input type="text" id='ford'/><br><br>
Hyndai price: <input type="text" id='hyundai'/>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var list = [
{ date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
{ date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
{ date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];
```

for accessing  the list use :

`list[index].date`

Comment: Is that the answer to a previous version of the question?