# js object which should store list of objects as property

Tags: javascript

If I have one object `myObj`

and I want that object to have property clients which will hold list of clientObjects with Id and Name properties

```
var client= { Id: ", Name: "};
var myObj= {
       clients: ????     
}
```

how can I populate client properties and use it in myObj.clients

Comment: put client list into array

Comment: `client: []` and then use `myObj.clients.push` to add

Comment: why downvoting guys . he is new in js .

Comment: @Mahi I guess reason of downvotes could be that OP has pretty good rep. and this means he/she should have searched given its a basic question.

Comment: @Rajesh in starting time it's hard to find answer because they don't the actual term used in the language.

Comment: @Mahi I'm not the downvoter. Also totally agree to it that terms are different, but a generic search on google will give you some information like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868850/creating-list-of-objects-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

May be this is what you want

```js
var myObj = {}; // Your 'myObj' object

// 'clients' property which will hold list of clientObjects
myObj.clients = [{
  id: "1",
  Name: "name1",
}, {
  id: "2",
  Name: "name2"
}];

console.log(myObj);
```

Comment: Do we need this: `myObj.clients = [];`?

Comment: I just decomposed to simple steps, just to give clarity to the OP

Comment: This will confuse beginners as that line is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Please review this one:

```js
//Following is Array of Client (aka object). Thats all you need
var clientList = [
  { Id: "id1", Name: "Name1"},
  { Id: "id2", Name: "Name2"},
  { Id: "id3", Name: "Name3"},
  { Id: "id4", Name: "Name4"},
  { Id: "id5", Name: "Name5"}
];

//and you can iterate through it in many ways, like this:
clientList.forEach(function(client) {
  console.log(`Client Id:${client.Id} Name:${client.Name}`);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you.....

```
var myObject = {clients:[]};
myObject.clients.push({id:"1",name:"name"});
myObject.clients.push({id:"2",name:"name"});
console.log(myObject);
```