# Creating a queue of songs Discord.js

Tags: bots, discord

I've finally figured out a way of make my Discord bot play audio from YouTube,using the library "yt-dl".

I've made all commands needed for play the song. 
Play, pause, stop(ends the song).

I did a simple command for the play such as, play the song, from the URL provided by the user. How could I maybe create a queue? And then, make it play the next song in the queue when the current one ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply just create a list for your songs, to check how to create a list, check this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868850/creating-list-of-objects-in-javascript#5868876). (You can also use an array, which may help if you just simply wants to restrict how long your queue can be)

(There is also a guy who created a list function for javascript, it works like .NET's generic list, you can check it out [here](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/29876/javascript-advanced-list).)

You might also want to create an object to store your song details to be inside your list.

Comment: Alright, that works.
But, I have a question, how'd I add something to the list each time, we do the command?

Comment: For arrays, `Array.push(<value>)` method, for list, it would be `list.add(<value>)` (Or pascal case for the methods).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
    var servers = {}; //obj


    var id = "HgzGwKwLmgM" //"something"
    //need provide id ^

    //example if with array <inside play function>
     if (!servers[message.guild.id]) servers[message.guild.id] = {
                    queue: [],
                    videodescription: [],
                    videolengh: [],
                    videotitle: [],
                    videothumbnailUrl: [],
                    videourl: []
                };

     server = servers[message.guild.id]; //method


    //fetchVideoInfo is part of nmp youtube-info@1.1.1
    //npm install youtube-info --save


server.queue.push(id);

     fetchVideoInfo(id, function (err, videoInfo) {
     if (err) throw new Error(err);

    message.reply(' The song: **' + videoInfo.title + "** has been added to the queue list.");

    server.videolengh.push(videoInfo.duration);//integer
    server.videothumbnailUrl.push(videoInfo.thumbnailUrl);
    server.videourl.push(videoInfo.url);
    server.videotitle.push(videoInfo.title);
    server.videodescription.push(videoInfo.description);

    //(videoInfo.description in fetchVideoInfo) returning html

    });

    //                              |
    //later you can call components V like but i will require method 

    console.log(server.queue[0] + "\n");
    //or
    console.log(server.videodescription[0]);


    //also don't forget to "skip"
    //example server.queue.shift();
```